# Access - When to make a query into a table

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

This is more of a philosophical question, than a technical question. I'm an Access noob and am running into a philosophical conundrum.

I've run some queries from my base tables. I have them pretty much how I want them, don't really foresee making additional changes.

So, my question is this: is there an advantage to keeping my data in queries? If they're going to be static queries, should I just make them into tables? Have I already made too many tables/is there such a thing?

I'm working with computer scans. The scans are looking at different things on the computer--these are 2 tables. I also have a master list of stuff that I put together. And then I have a list of printers.

Then, I have like 7 queries. They're things like looking for intersects between the different scans, comparing the results of scans to lists of printers, etc. etc.

So, yeah. Do I keep them as queries, does it not matter, or should I make them into tables if they're just going to be static?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

welcome to stack overflow.

You are going to need to provide much more detail if you want specific help in these forums.  Showing us details of what you've already accomplished helps a lot.  Also showing more details on where you are trying to get to is helpful.  You might want to read the site rules for how to post a [well formed question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

As for databases... there are many ways to construct a database depending on the amount of data fields as well as amount of data in those fields.

If you have a relatively small database that doesn't change, you can break with conventions and clump data into rough tables.  But it's very advisable to NOT do that.  Because if you ever need to change the tables or add new data... it starts to become a nightmare fairly quickly.

Which brings up the question: what are well formed tables in a database and how are they connected?

The answer usually takes going to some database classes.  But you can start by looking up what [Third Normal Form](http://www.andrewrollins.com/2009/08/11/database-normalization-first-second-and-third-normal-forms/) is.  This will give you an idea of how to break down data into tables that are manageable and easy to expand upon.

But Third Normal Form is not always the best way to store data.  Sometimes for reporting purposes, it's better to have tables in second normal form or lower to give you more speed on retrieval.  (Mind you, this is usually for databases with massive amounts of data.)

Anyway, it's worth looking up articles on database design or taking a class.  The more you understand about how data is retrieved and stored, the better you will be at deciding what the best structure is for you.

If you post more details, I'm sure people from stack overflow will help give you more pointers.

Best of luck! :)